# yFinance: .download / .history function only provides data from 1pm to 7pm (Python)

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I am currently facing the following problem.

When I try to download stock-prices either way:

```
import yfinance as yf
loaded_data = yf.download(tickers=ticker, period="7d", interval="1m")
```

or

```
ticker_dat = yf.Ticker(ticker)
loaded_data = ticker_dat.history(period="7d", interval="1m")
```

It only gives me data from 1pm to 7pm. Does anybody know, how I can receive data for the whole day? Would be cute :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Is that maybe regular trading hours plus or minus some time difference?

Comment: @nehalem That is what I thought, but the stock prices changes every time even outside the trading hours. It has to be possible to get those data...